# Connecting to user dbus as root

Tags: python, linux, dbus

If we open a python interpreter normally and enter the following:

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
bus.list_names()
```

We see all the services on the user's session dbus. Now suppose we wanted to do some root-only things in the same script to determine information to pass through dbus, so we run the interpreter with `sudo python` and run the same thing, we only see a short list of items on the root user's session dbus, and attempting to connect to anything that was on the user dbus with `get_object` produces a not found error accordingly.

So far I've tried inserting

```
import os

os.seteuid(int(os.environ['SUDO_UID']))
```

But this only makes `SessionBus()` give a `org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply` so this is probably nonsense. Is there a way to connect to a user's dbus service as a super user, with the python dbus bindings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have little knowledge about DBus, but that question got me curious.

TL;DR: Use `dbus.bus.BusConnection` with the socket address for the target user and `seteuid` for gaining access.

First question: What socket does DBus connect to for the session bus?

```sh
$ cat list_bus.py 
import dbus
print(dbus.SessionBus().list_names())
$ strace -o list_bus.trace python3 list_bus.py
$ grep ^connect list_bus.trace 
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/user/1000/bus"}, 20) = 0
```

Maybe it relies on environment variables for this? Gotcha!

```sh
$ env|grep /run/user/1000/bus
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

Stracing the behaviour from the root account it appears that it does not know the address to connect to. Googling for the variable name got me to the [D-Bus Specification](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html), section "Well-known Message Bus Instances".

Second question: Can we connect directly to the socket without having the D-Bus library guess the right address? The [dbus-python tutorial](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/tutorial.html#connecting-to-the-bus) states:

> For special purposes, you might use a non-default Bus, or a connection which isn’t a Bus at all, using some new API added in dbus-python 0.81.0.

Looking at the [changelog](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/news.html#d-bus-python-bindings-0-81-0-9-may-2007), this appears to refer to these:

> Bus has a superclass dbus.bus.BusConnection (a connection to a bus daemon, but without the shared-connection semantics or any deprecated API) for the benefit of those wanting to subclass bus daemon connections

Let's try this out:

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
>>> from dbus.bus import BusConnection
>>> len(BusConnection("unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus").list_names())
145
```

How about root access?

```
# python3
>>> from dbus.bus import BusConnection
>>> len(BusConnection("unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus").list_names())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 124, in __new__
    bus = cls._new_for_bus(address_or_type, mainloop=mainloop)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not
  receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send
  a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout
  expired, or the network connection was broken.
>>> import os
>>> os.seteuid(1000)
>>> len(BusConnection("unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus").list_names())
143
```

*So this answers the question*: Use `BusConnection` instead of `SessionBus` and specify the address explicitly, combined with `seteuid` to gain access.

### Bonus: Connect as root without seteuid

Still I'd like to know if it is possible
to access the bus directly as root user, without resorting to `seteuid`. After
a few search queries, I found [a systemd ticket](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6249)
with this remark:

> dbus-daemon is the component enforcing access ... (but you can drop an xml policy file in, to make it so).

This led me to an [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365363/where-should-dbus-session-local-conf-be-created) discussing how to modify the site local session bus policy.

Just to play with it, I ran this in one terminal:

```sh
$ cp /usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf session.conf
$ (edit session.conf to modify the include for local customization)
$ diff /usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf session.conf
50c50
<   <include ignore_missing="yes">/etc/dbus-1/session-local.conf</include>
---
>   <include ignore_missing="yes">session-local.conf</include>
$ cat > session-local.conf
<busconfig>
  <policy context="mandatory">
    <allow user="root"/>
  </policy>
</busconfig>
$ dbus-daemon --config-file session.conf --print-address
unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-j0r67hLIuh,guid=d100052e45d06f248242109262325b98
$ dbus-daemon --config-file session.conf --print-address
unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-j0r67hLIuh,guid=d100052e45d06f248242109262325b98
```

In another terminal, I can not attach to this bus as a root user:

```
# python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
>>> from dbus.bus import BusConnection
>>> address = "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-j0r67hLIuh,guid=d100052e45d06f248242109262325b98"
>>> BusConnection(address).list_names()
dbus.Array([dbus.String('org.freedesktop.DBus'), dbus.String(':1.0')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
```

This should also enable accessing *all* session busses on the system, when installing `session-local.conf` globally:

```
# cp session-local.conf /etc/dbus-1/session-local.conf
# kill -HUP 1865   # reload config of my users session dbus-daemon
# python3
>>> from dbus.bus import BusConnection
>>> len(BusConnection("unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus").list_names())
143
```

And it works - now root can connect to any session bus without resorting to `seteuid`. Don't forget to

```
# rm /etc/dbus-1/session-local.conf
```

if your root user does not need this power.

Comment: Such a great answer that will be helpful for times to come, thanks especially for spending the time to explaining dbus policies \o/ I'm wondering if it'd be possible to only allow root to access all sessions, and why that's not the common case?

While this is the best answer to the original question, it would be better to avoid running python as root altogether, and just escalate the privileges where necessary.

Comment: Resolves the issue, with a heap of context too.

For the thing about defaults from teprrr, usually user dbus is application software that a root user shouldn't care about or need to send dbus signals to, so root normally doesn't get to see user dbus.

Answer (score 1):

Bluehorn's answer helped me. I figured I'd share my solution. I'm only a few months into learning Python (coming from just shell scripting) so if this is really wrong and just happens to work on my system please let me know.

These are parts from a daemon I wrote to monitor CPU temps and control the fan speeds in Linux so it needs root permissions. Not sure how well it would work if ran as a regular user when multiple users are logged in. I'm guessing it wouldn't...

```py
import os, pwd
from dbus import SessionBus, Interface
from dbus.bus import BusConnection

# Subclassing dbus.Interface because why not

class Dbus(Interface):
    def __init__(self, uid):
        method = 'org.freedesktop.Notifications'
        path = '/' + method.replace('.', '/')
        if os.getuid() == uid:
            obj = SessionBus().get_object( method, path )
        else:
            os.seteuid(uid)
            obj = BusConnection( "unix:path=/run/user/" + str(uid) + "/bus" )
            obj.get_object( method, path )

        super().__init__(obj, method)

# Did this so my notifications would work
# when running as root or non root

class DbusNotificationHandler:

    app_icon = r"/path/to/my/apps/icon.png"
    name     = "MacFanD"

    def __init__(self):
        loggedIn, users = [ os.getlogin() ], []
        for login in pwd.getpwall():
            if login.pw_name in loggedIn:
                users.append( login.pw_uid )

        self.users = []
        for i in users:
            self.users.append( Dbus(i) )

    def notification(self, msg, mtype=None):
        if not isinstance(msg, list) or len(msg) < 2:
            raise TypeError("Expecting a list of 2 for 'msg' parameter")

        hint = {}

        if mtype == 'temp':
            icon = 'dialog-warning'
            hint['urgency'] = 2
            db_id = 498237618
            timeout = 0
        elif mtype == 'warn':
            icon = 'dialog-warning'
            hint['urgency'] = 2
            db_id = 0
            timeout = 5000
        else:
            icon = self.app_icon
            hint['urgency'] = 1
            db_id = 0
            timeout = 5000

        for db in self.users:
            db.Notify( self.name, db_id, icon, msg[0], msg[1:], [], hint, timeout )

handler = DbusNotificationHandler()
notify = handler.notification

msg = [ "Daemon Started", "Daemon is now running - %s"%os.getpid() ]
notify(msg)

temp = "95 Celsius"
msg = [ "High Temp Warning", "CPU temperature has reached %s"%temp ]
notify(msg, 'warn')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable to choose the dbus session you want to connect to.

Incorrect permissions (i.e., missing the `seteuid`) causes an immediate `NoReply`, and not defining `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` responded with `Using X11 for dbus-daemon autolaunch was disabled at compile time, set your DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS instead`.

Here's the test code I used:

```
import os
import dbus

# become user
uid = os.environ["SUDO_UID"]
print(f"I'm {os.geteuid()}, becoming {uid}")
os.seteuid(int(uid))

# set the dbus address
os.environ["DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"] = f"unix:path=/run/user/{uid}/bus"

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
print(bus.list_names())

# I'm 0, becoming 1000
# dbus.Array([dbus.String('org.freedesktop.DBus'), dbus.String('org.fr .. <snip>
```